# Counter-pressure bottle filler and exposure to oxygen

Tags: pressure, bottle, oxygenation, packaging

I have a question about the process of using a counter-pressure bottle filler to transfer beer from my keg into bottles and how to keep the beer from being exposed to Oxygen in the process.

I'm using [this bottle filler](https://www.braupartner.de/Gegendruckabfueller-ohne-Adapter). Sorry it's in German, but you should get the picture. It's the usual 4-way beer-in, beer-out, co2 in, co2 out system.

My question is:

When the bottle is completely filled with beer I remove the tube from the bottle slowly and this causes the beer to slunk down into the bottle. Doesn't this pull oxygen into the top of the bottle?

There isn't enough foam at the top to protect from oxygen. Is this ok, or should I be doing something different?

Answer (score 1):

My filler is a bit different, but it's the same principle. What I usually do is continue filling while I'm pulling out the tube to keep the foam at the top of the neck. I have my bottle sitting in a small pale to keep mess to a minimum. Seems to work OK and I can still cap on foam.